# sortable and date range limited, data model using NoSQL solution

Tags: database-design, nosql, cassandra, data-modeling

I try to model a view on cassandra.
So the view looks like this:

```
link name | unique visits | non unique visits | ...
---------------------------------------------------
page 1    | 4             | 8                 | ...
page 2    | 2             | 4                 | ...
page 3    | 3             | 8                 | ...
page 4    | 1             | 1                 | ...
page 5    | 9             | 11                | ...
...

<page1><page2><page3>...<page n>
```

So the main requirement here is that I need to show that data for a specified date range. For example the user
can change "from" and "to" date pickers and "unique visits" | "non unique visits" should display the sum of clicks
in that date range.
The other requirement that is killing all my trials is that the data should be sortable on "unique visits" and "non unique visits" base.

I've done such model in the past MySql using the following scheme:
    link_id             bigint
    date                datetime
    unique_visits           int
    non_unique_visits       int

where (link_id, date) -> primary key

So something like the query bellow was giving a satisfying result.

SELECT link_id, date, SUM(unique_visits) AS unique_visits_sum, SUM(non_unique_visits) AS non_unique_visits_sum 
FROM agg_clicks
GROUP BY link_id, date
ORDER BY unique_visits DESC
LIMIT 0, 50

But as you understand this is not too scalable and the performance of the query depends on page count and the days count.
Another issue is that a full table scan is needed to perform the sorting on a calculated field.

So, data modeling experts, PLEASE!!! a little advise. 
And thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I would recommend you to narrow down the query parameters, and calculate all potential results offline in advance.

Comment: yeah sure, its a solution, but the problem is that there could be >100k of links per user, do you think its a good idea to extract 100k of objects from db? is it a usual practice to extract 100k of objects per user request? thanks

Comment: or you mean to create a collection per every potential view? In this case how could I structure the data? I have date range it could be an year or some days. There are a lot of potential results. thanks